# Problems running rake db:migrate in a Ruby on Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, dbmigrate

I am trying to run rake db:migrate in my Ruby on Rails application.

However, it is giving me a "uninitialized constant" exception.  From Googling this, it looks like the solution is to update the rake version.  So I changed my gemfile and ran bundle update.

However, the exception is still happening... I think because I didn't update the right rake library.

How do I fix this?  How can I update rake for the other path too, or exclusively run rake through the bundle thing?

```
My-Comp:my_project username$ bundle show rake
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2
My-Comp:my_project username$ which rake
/usr/bin/rake
My-Comp:my_project username$ rake -V
rake, version 0.8.7

(See - they are not the same!)

My-Comp:my_project username$ rake db:migrate --trace
(in /Users/username/projects/my_project)
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Rake::DSL
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2503:in `const_missing'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/tasklib.rb:8
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rdoc-3.12/lib/rdoc/task.rb:37:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rdoc-3.12/lib/rdoc/task.rb:37
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/tasks/documentation.rake:2:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/tasks/documentation.rake:2
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/tasks.rb:15:in `load'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/tasks.rb:15
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/tasks.rb:6:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/tasks.rb:6
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:289:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:289:in `initialize_tasks'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/railtie.rb:184:in `instance_exec'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/railtie.rb:184:in `load_tasks'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/railtie.rb:184:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/railtie.rb:184:in `load_tasks'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:424:in `load_tasks'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:145:in `load_tasks'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `send'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/Users/username/projects/my_project/Rakefile:7
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2383:in `load'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2383:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2017:in `load_rakefile'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2016:in `load_rakefile'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2000:in `run'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/usr/bin/rake:31
```

Comment: What do you have in your Gemfile? You should specify the version of rake you want and run bundle install. Also, which version of Ruby are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this command:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

`bundle exec` executes a command in the context of your gemfile.

Comment: OK, I think that worked. How can I update the other rake too?  I tried gem update rake and it just says nothing to update.  (I'd prefer to have a working rake rather than run exec all the time!)

Comment: 'Other rake too' - you mean in other projects? You should assign the rake version in the gemfile of these projects.

Comment: No, I don't mean other projects.  I mean that I don't really understand the version management, so I think I've got myself two versions of rake.  One is /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2 the other is /usr/bin/rake.  /usr/bin/rake is 0.8.7 and I need to upgrade it too, but can't figure out how.  Or I need it so that "rake" executes the gem rake instead of the other one.  (Look at the output I pasted in the answer)

Comment: You should install rubygems and let this ruby's packaging system to  resolve such kind of problems. The bundler will resolve the dependencies in context of project.

Comment: I added these two lines to my Rakefile, and it seems to work now (with a warning about a couple already initialized CONSTANTS: require 'rake/dsl_definition'
require 'rake'